# Python socket unable to connect through public ip on the same machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, client

Hello yesterday I started creating python programs with use of tcp sockets. My code is Here

Server:

```
import socket

IP = '192.168.1.20'
PORT = 2222

BUFFER = 16

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((IP,PORT))
s.listen(True)

c = s.accept()[0]

c.send(b'test')

c.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

IP = '83.27.192.55'
PORT = 2222

BUFFER = 16

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((IP,PORT))

print(s.recv(BUFFER).decode('utf-8'))

s.close()
```

The thing is it works perfectly fine with private IP but when I switch to public IP client is unable to connect to server. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

edit

I searched deeper and found out that every single device in my network has the same public IP could this be the reason why can't I use public IP but private IP works perfectly fine?

Comment: Try changing the IP to localhost `'127.0.0.1'`

Comment: the server binds to `192.168.1.20` causes it only respond to packet targeted at `192.168.1.20` not the public one? Try bind to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Is your public ip accessible?

Comment: also try using a port number of above 5000 (not solution a suggestion (maybe solves something))

Comment: could it possibly be that You are trying to connect to that IP while using the internet from that router? (or however this stuff works) maybe connect to a different wifi network? oh, for which You will need two machines

Comment: using `127.0.0.1` aswell as using 0.0.0.0 did nothing

Comment: @PaulWasilewski how can I check if my ip is accessible?